# Can we get results from base class to derived class in inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, calculation

Suppose we have variable `z` in class `A` which stores addition of two numbers, and variable `w` in class `B` which stores subtraction of two numbers, and we create a derived class `D` - can we bring these values stored in `z` and  `w` to the derived class `D` so that we can multiply these numbers?

The code would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class c1
{
    int x, y;

public:
    void getdata1(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    void add1()
    {
        int z = x + y;
        cout << "the sum is " << z << endl;
    }
};

class c2
{
    int x, y;

public:
    void getdata2(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    void sub1()
    {
        int w = x - y;
        cout << "the sum is " << w << endl;
    }

};

class D: public c1, public c2
{
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout << "the product is s" << z + w; // something like this
    }
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    D obj1;

    obj1.getdata1(10, 5);
    obj1.getdata2(10, 5);
    obj1.add1();
    obj1.sub1();
    obj1.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please, for the love of all that is good, format your code properly. also, don't write methods called `getdata()` that actually **set** data...

Comment: `z` and `w` are not data members of classes `c1` and `c2` respectively. They are local variables in their respective functions. If you want `z` and `w` to be inherited in `D`, you should declare them as public/protected members in their respective classes.

Comment: BTW: The example looks like a fully misunderstanding what data members are made for and also what methods are good for. Also the OOP design can't be seen here, because multiple data members represents multiple "objects" in one instance... Looks so bad to me!

Comment: I understood the problem. the variables,z and w from class A and class B respectively, had to be initialized as public variables and not in functions . So that those variables can be multiplied in the derived class, D.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
#include <iostream>

class c1
{
    int x,y;
public:
    c1(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}

    int sum() const { return x + y; }
};

class c2
{
    int x,y;
public:
    c2(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}

    int sub() const { return x - y; }
};

class D: public c1, public c2
{
public:
    D(int a, int b) : c1(a, b), c2(a, b) {}

    int foo() const { return sum() * sub(); }
};

int main(){
    D obj(10, 5);

    std::cout << "the sum is " << obj.sum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the sub is " << obj.sub() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the product is " << obj.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This programs gives the output which i wanted.

Comment: But how does **c1(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}** work

Comment: Look at [initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to work on formatting of question , here  i assume here that you want code for multiplication of those two variables(z and w) .

```
#include using namespace std;
 int x,y,z,w;
class c1{
    int x,y;
public:void getdata1(int a, int b){
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    void add1()
    {
        int z=x+y;
        cout<<"the sum is "<<z<<endl;
        return z ;
    }
}

class c2 {
 int x,y;
public:void getdata2(int a, int b){
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    void sub1()
    {
        int w=x-y;
        cout<<"the sum is "<<w<<endl;
        return w ;
    }

}
class D: public c1,public c2
{
public:void multiply(int a, int b)
{
     cout<<"the multiplication is "<<z*w<<endl;
}
public static int main(){

    D obj1;
    obj1.getdata1(10,5);
    obj1.getdata2(10,5);
    int a = obj1.add1();
    int b = obj1.sub1();
    obj1.display();
    obj1.multiply(a,b)
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this is the solution you were expecting .

Comment: This works if the return type of the functions(add1 and sub1) are int

Comment: yep , but you can use any datatype as per problem statement . if you are unsure about the size of data , just use long int .